# Combine xlFilterValues with xlOR for other columns

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I have a macro where I want to autofilter values. I have a list of values on one sheet which I want to filter.

If there are multiple values to be found (with or operator), they are delimited by comma in the cell. Here is the code that I run over multiple columns (this is an example for column D only)

```
If DL.Cells(i, "D").Value <> vbNullString Then

    If InStr(1, DL.Cells(i, "D").Value, ",", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        arr = Split(DL.Cells(i, "D").Value, ",", , vbTextCompare)
        tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=35, Criteria1:=arr, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    Else
        tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=35, Criteria1:="=" & DL.Cells(i, "D").Value, Operator:=xlOr
    End If

End If
```

I need to go over multiple columns and filter our either a single value or multiple values. And I want to have the relationship between columns to be xlor. So if I filter based on criteria written in five columns, if any of them is met, the record will be included.

The problem is that if my first column was filtered with `tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=35, Criteria1:=arr, Operator:=xlFilterValues` and the second column was filtered with  `tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=36, Criteria1:="=" & DL.Cells(i, "E").Value, Operator:=xlOr` it does not take into account that I want to both filter multiple values in one column or have a single value in second column or multiple values in thrid column etc.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Autofilter is always applied as an `And` across columns, not an `Or`. You could use an advanced filter or add a formula column that evaluates your conditions, then filter that (eg for True/False).

Comment: Thank you very much. I will rework the code to filter one column at the time and copy the results to another sheet instead.

Comment: Just bear in mind you could in principle end up with duplicates that way.

Comment: Thank you for a notice. I will just add a helper column with row number and then I will remove duplicates from the results by that column.